# how to activate context menu for listview item not for Column Headers

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, contextmenu

I am having my Listview as follows

```
 Header1      Header2      Header3
  Item1        Item2        Item3
  Item1        Item2        Item3
  Item1        Item2        Item3
```

I have written a code to show `context menu` on clicking the `list view` but it is showing the `Context menu` on `headers` too. I need to display `Context menu` only when user clicks on `Items` of `list view` can any one help me

This is my code I written at present

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView1, e.Location);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the HeaderStyle to non clickable?

Comment: did you apply context menu from the properties of listview?

Comment: Can you post a short and complete set of code that replicates the issue? What version of .net are you using? Which control events are you handling?

Answer (score 13):

How about this?

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView = sender as ListView;
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ListViewItem item = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView , e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

This sets it up so the context menu only shows if the right click happens on an item, because if the right click happens on a header or something else then item will be null. Hope it helps

Answer (score 10):

This could be useful for you

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (listView1.FocusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
        } 
    }
```

The "`Bounds`" property is a rectangle that represents the edges of the "`FocusedItem`" in pixels. So if the cursor is in this rectangle area when mouse right clicked then the "`contextMenuStrip1`" shows up.

Answer (score 5):

You can cancel the viewing of the context menu if there are no items selected, which will be valid only if you right click an item

```
    /// <summary>
    /// ContextMenuStrip Opening Action
    /// </summary>
    private void listContextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // If there are no items selected, cancel viewing the context menu
        if (connectionListView.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for using this event. More keyboard compatible than depending on a mouseclick.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite dirty...just using the information at hand. Someone will probably come with a better answer.

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.Location.Y > headerHeightDefinedEarlier )
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView1, e.Location);
}
```

Comment: what you mean by `headerHeightDefinedEarlier`

Comment: I meant that you define headerHeight somewhere in code. You could also just replace the code with if (e.Location.Y > 15), but like i said, it is dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You should to select the item when you are doing click on it. Then you may ask for the selecteditems in the list and get the selected element index:  `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index`

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index == 0)
return;
```

Comment: I thought about this one too. Problem here I think would be that if you first select an item, then right click the header, the context menu would still be showing cause you still have your previous item selected.

Comment: You should select the item in the SelectedIndexChanged event